# linux command to get lines in specified format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I have data in csv in the following form:

```
  1    number     tab    one
  2    number two
  3    number three
```

Now I want to convert the data to the following form:

```
  1    number tab one
  2    number two
  3    number three
```

i.e. I want the first tab to remain as it is..but the second and consecutive tabs to be replaced by spaces. Is it possible to do so using a linux command (like sed, etc). I know I can use sed for substitution but is it possible to make it skip the first tab space and start substitution from the second tab space.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `awk`.

Comment: @JimGarrison I tried sed 's/^[ \t]*//' but it does not seem to do the needful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\t/ /2g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, you can do like this.

```
cat file
1       number  tab     one
2       number two
3       number three
```

The `awk`

```
awk '{$1=$1;sub(/ /,"\t")}1'
1       number tab one
2       number two
3       number three
```

`$1=$1` sets all spaces to default one space.

`sub(/ /,"\t")` changes first spaces to a tab

`1` print everything

PS You can skip first tab using a for loop and going trough all fields, but why make it more complicated then needed when the function are there?  Only school work has this type of request.

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the first tab ain't easy.

But you could reframe the problem this way:

1. Replace all the tabs with spaces
2. Replace the first space with tab

This may be a bit lossy, but it's actually negligible, and the outcome is the same:

```
sed -e 's/    / /g; s/ /      /' < yourfile.txt
```

To enter TAB characters on the command line you may have to type `Ctrl-V TAB`.

In older implementations of `sed` where semicolon doesn't work to separate two commands you can use 2 `-e` expressions instead:

```
sed -e 's/    / /g' -e 's/ /      /' < yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file
1   number     tab    one
2   number two
3   number three
```

Try this:

```
sed 's/\s\+/ /2g' file
1   number tab one
2   number two
3   number three
```